# Angular/Universal app - https request( this.httpClient.get ) is not executing on a server

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I try to develop an Angular/Universal app and have encountered the issue - when I have my build uploaded to a Node.js server the app doesn't render my dynamic HTML(static only) as HTTP requests are not executing at all. I tried to build the Hero Universal example and it works it should do. I've turned JS script off on my browser and the server renders dynamic HTML(app heroes list).

How do I achieve the functionality with my app?

Comment: url should be full (not relative) urls if you want them executed on server

Comment: Thanks Normunds! I've added UniversalInterceptor like at the angular.io universal Hero app example.